# Observable typescript error on .startWith([])

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I get the following typescript error:

> Error:(34, 20) TS2345: Argument of type 'undefined[]' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'number | Scheduler'.  Type
>   'undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'Scheduler'.  Property 'now'
>   is missing in type 'undefined[]'.

when using startWith in this context:

```
items$:any = Observable
        .interval(250)
        .map((_:any) => Math.random())
        .startWith([])
        .scan((acc:any, curr:any)=> [...acc, curr]);
```

wondering of any way to cast to avoid the error?

regards

Sean

Answer (score 4):

```
show = false;
items$:any = Observable
    .interval(500)
    .delay(500)
    .map((_:any) => Math.random())
    .startWith(<any>[])
    .scan((acc:any, curr:any)=> [...acc, curr]);
```

adding any did the trick